# Fetching public profile contents of any facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I fetch the public profile contents of any facebook user?

I tried `https://graph.facebook.com/[FB-USER-ID]?access_token=[MY-ACCESS-TOKEN]`, but this gives me the public profile contents of only my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you skip passing `access_token` you'll be getting only public information (you also may get specific fields of profile using `fields` argument)

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=id,name,gender,link,picture&type=large
```

Learn more about [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) object and his `fields` (only those marked as *No `access_token` required* are publicly available) in [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: Is it possible to get the user's location without any user authorization? I can't find this information in the /[USER_ID] graph api call

Comment: @serpent403, no `location` is only available after user have granted `user_location`/`friends_location` permission to your application which is also means you should authorize user...

Comment: @CBroe, no offense. OP commented before I've updated the answer with links to documentation ;)